# Como calcular valor de dois inputs um de tipo range e outro option e imprimir resultado em tempo real?

Tags: javascript, html5, input, matemática

Galera, gostaria de saber como posso estar efetuando um cáculo, no qual e pegaria um valor de tipo range e o valor de um option e imprimisse o resultado em tempo real, porém mesmo se nenhum option for selecionado e apenas o range for mudado o valor seja mostrado mesmo assim.

Um exemplo de código JS, porém não funcional.
https://jsfiddle.net/hnropn0p/

Porém gostaria de fazer apenas com JavaScript, sem o uso de frameworks ou bibliotecas. Eu já conferi o código do exemplo acima, e foi usado JQuery, e os valores de cada produto são armazenaos em arrays e não nos inputs.

Comment: A tua pergunta está pouco clara e falta-lhe código. Podes melhorar a pergunta pf? (não uses links para sites externos)

Comment: Opá! certamente, vou postar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function generateResult()
{
  result.innerHTML = +select.value * +range.value;
};

generateResult();

document.querySelectorAll('.observe').forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('change', generateResult);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Range
  <input type="range" value="2" class="observe" id="range">
</div>

<div>
  Multiplicado por
  <select id="select" class="observe">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  Resultado
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Basta trocar o retorno da função `generateResult` pela operação que você quer usar.